# IE8 hover issue, making page disappear

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, hover

I've got a weird problem with IE8, every other browser displays everything fine, but no matter what I do IE8 just won't play nice.

I've got a grid of divs, each .gridCell div contains amongst other elements a hidden div that I'd like to reveal on hover.

So far, I've tried applying a class to the .gridCell div on hover with javascript and using css to set the preview div to display block using the .hover class. Works perfectly in every browser besides IE8, which when hovering makes the whole page disappear until you move the mouse again.

I've also tried various attempts using jquery to animate the hidden div on hover, which all work, again in every browser, yet in IE8 on hover the whole page jumps to the top on hover no matter which version I try.

[I've put up a rough test case here](http://www.lee-ellam.com/ie8-issue/ie8-issue.html).

In my scrappy demo, there are z-index issues, but these can be ignored as in the proper version they're sorted, this is just to illustrate the problem.  Scroll down to the second row using jquery, and in IE8 the page will jump up to the top on hover.

I'm sure I'm just missing something simple here, but the more I look at it the more frustrated I get!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your page get a double `<body>` element on IE. I'd fix that first.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know.. When I load your page up in IE8 it defaults to IE7 compatibility mode telling me there was an error on the page The last row of hover elements are causing the issue. Its jumping to the top of the page because it encounters an error when you hover, causing the page to reload in browser compatibility mode.

Comment: Hmm, when I'm opening it according to developer tools its in IE8 rendering in IE8 standards mode.  Any idea on what the problem with the JS could be, especially as it's working in every other browser I've tested (IE6, IE7, FF, Safari, Chrome)?

Comment: please add !DOCTYPE of html5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I worked out what was causing the problem.  The div I was using for the trigger was positioned relatively from something unrelated I'd done earlier but then scrapped, removing the declaration fixed the page jumping in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

the only issue i came across in ie 8 and other versions was z-index and nothing else. can u provide a screenshot or something to look into what you are getting. page isn't disappearing for me

Comment: For whatever reason, it's not doing it on IE8 at home, was only happening at work, which is odd to say the least.  The main problem I'd like to sort is the hoverIntent version at the bottom scrolling the page up to the top on hover as this is the version I'd like to use (same problem happening without using hoverIntent, just tried that to see if it would remedy the issue).